# JS function undefined when calling from certain click events in handlebars template

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

I am not understanding why the function goToProfile(otherUserId) is 'not defined' only some of the times.

For example, on the page, I have a link to a user that works fine by using the '.userProfileLink' click event.

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(user.avatar.url(:medium)), "/profile/#{user.id}/view", class: "userProfileLink", :"value" => user.id, remote: true %>
```

Then I click #requestMeeting which renders this handlebars template:

```
<script id="request-meeting-form" type="text/x-handlebars-template">


    <form id="requestMeetingForm">
        <div class="form_section">

            <h4 style="text-align:center;">Request 1 Hour Meeting</h4>
            <br>
            <div class="wrapper_input col_8_of_16">

                <h4 class="label_standard">Date</h4>

                <input type="text" id="meeting_date" class="input_standard datePicker" onfocus="this.blur()"></input>

                <input type="hidden" id="alt_meeting_date" class="input_standard datePicker"></input>

            </div>

            <div class="wrapper_input col_4_of_16">

                <h4 class="label_standard">Start Time</h4>          
                <input type="text" id="meeting_time" class="input_standard time_picker" onfocus="this.blur()"></input>

            </div>


        </div>

        <div class="form_section">


        <div class="wrapper_input">
            <a href="#" type="button" id="suggestedLocations" class="btn_secondary" >Find a place to meet <svg class="chat"><use xlink:href="#map"/></use></svg></a>
        </div>
            <br>
            <div class="wrapper_input col_8_of_16">
                <input type="text" name="location" id="locationField" placeholder="Location Name" class="input_standard" ></input>
            </div>{{!--  
            --}}<div class="wrapper_input col_8_of_16">
                <input type="text" name="location_address" id="addressField" placeholder="Location Address" class="input_standard"></input>
            </div>


            <input type="hidden" id="currentUser"></input>


        </div>

            <div id="mapLocation">

        </div>
       **************** IMPORTANT PART *********************

        <div class="form_section submit_cancel">
             <div class="wrapper_input cancel" >
                <a href='#' class="link_cancel" id="goToProfile" value={{userId}}>Cancel<svg class="meeting_cancel"><use xlink:href="#circleClose"/></svg></a>
             </div>

           ********************************************
            <div class="wrapper_input submit">
               <div class="actions">
                <button type="submit" class="btn_primary" id="requestMeetingButton" >Request Meeting <svg class="" ><use xlink:href="#sendPlane"/></svg></button>
               </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>


</script>
```

When I try to call goToProfile again in the template above, I get an error that goToProfile is not defined.

application.js:

```
$(document).on('click', '#goToProfile', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).attr('value')
        var otherUserId = parseInt(value);
        $('#profileSection').empty();
        goToProfile(otherUserId);
});


var ready;

ready = function(){


        var currentUserId;
        getCurrentUser().done(function() {
              var currentUserId = currentUserId
        });

        $('.userProfileLink').click(function(e) {
            var value = $(this).attr('value')
            otherUserId = value;
            goToProfile(otherUserId);

        });



        var profileSource = $("#user-profile").html();
        var compiledProfile = Handlebars.compile(profileSource);

        var languageSource = $("#languages").html();
        var compiledLanguage = Handlebars.compile(languageSource);
        var language = ""

        var currentUserId;

        var goToProfile = function(otherUserId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/get_user',
                type: 'GET',
                data: {otherUserId: otherUserId},
                success: function(user) {
                     var profileInfo;
                     getUserImage(otherUserId).done(function()  {
                        var profileInfo = {
                            first_name: user.first_name,
                            location: user.location,
                            bio: user.bio,
                            nationality: user.nationality,
                            userId: user.id,
                            userImage: userImage,

                        };
                     var profileTemplate = compiledProfile(profileInfo);
                     $('.yieldedInfo').empty();
                     $('.yieldedInfo').append('<div class="profileContainer">' + profileTemplate + '</div>');
                     });

                    getLanguagesUsers(user.id);

                    $('#requestMeeting').click(function(e)  {
                        e.preventDefault();
                        requestMeetingForm(this.value);

                    });
                },
                error: function(err)    {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            });

         };



         var getLanguagesUsers = function(userId)   {
                $.ajax({
                        url: '/user_languages',
                        type: 'GET',
                        data: {userId: userId},
                        success: function(languages)    {
                            for(var i=0; i<languages.length; i++)   {

                                if(languages[i].level != 5) {
                                     var id = languages[i].language_id
                                     var langUrl = '/languages/'+id;
                                      $.getJSON(langUrl, function(lang) {
                                        var language = lang.language

                                        var languageInfo = {
                                            language: language
                                        };
                                        var languageTemplate = compiledLanguage(languageInfo);
                                        $('#learningLanguages').append(languageTemplate);

                                     });

                                } else {
                                    var id = languages[i].language_id;
                                    var langUrl = '/languages/'+id;
                                    $.getJSON(langUrl, function(lang)   {
                                        var language = lang.language
                                        var languageInfo = {
                                            language: language
                                        };
                                        var languageTemplate = compiledLanguage(languageInfo);
                                        $('#fluentLanguages').append(languageTemplate);
                                     });
                                };
                            };

                        },
                        error: function(err)    {
                            console.log(err);
                        }
                     });
        };




};

$(document).ready(ready);
$(document).on('page:load', ready);
```

How can I make goToProfile() available to be called all the time?
Thanks!

Comment: its really no good programming but: `window.goToProfile = function(otherUserId)`

Comment: You need to bind the event handler to the function at the same level of scope, rather than via an inline handler.

Comment: @Archer sorry, I'm new to javascript. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you need by binding the click event handler at the same scope level as the function it needs to call...

```
var ready = function(){

    $(document).on('click', '#goToProfile', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var value = $(this).attr('value')
        var otherUserId = parseInt(value);
        $('#profileSection').empty();
        goToProfile(otherUserId);
    });

    // the rest of your ready function goes here

};
```

If you do it that way then the event handler has access to the `goToProfile` function as they're both within the `ready` function.  Nothing outside that function can access the private methods inside it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!! This works, and I understand now what you mean by 'same level of scope'

Comment: No problem - glad to have helped :)